# Determine which node.js programs are running

Tags: node.js, upstart

Is there a way to check which node.js servers are currently running on a machine? I launch a web server using an Upstart script and would like to see or get some sort of notification if it has crashed.

Comment: @RickardZachrisson: If you put this in an answer, I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the bash shell (terminal window)

Type:

ps aux | grep node

:)